# Загрузка текста из файла scikit-learn

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Подскажите пример кода, загружающий в память содержимое текстового файла для дальнейшей обработки (классификаци) загруженных файлов при помощи библиотеки scikit-learn.

Нашёл на просторах вот такой код:

```
import ast
import glob
import os

def my_load_files(folder, pattern):
    pathname = os.ntpath.join(folder, pattern)
    for filename in glob.glob(pathname):
        with open(filename) as file:
            yield filename

text_folder = 'O:\parsed'
print (my_load_files(text_folder, 'article_*'))
```

Он работает, но результатом выводит:

> < generator object my_load_files at 0x0000000003664168>

При попытке понять, что происходит посредством отладки, PyCharm не входит в функцию `my_load_files`.

Comment: [yield](https://habrahabr.ru/post/132554/) -  print( list( my_load_files(text_folder, 'article_*') ))

Comment: Вам надо загрузить один текстовый файл? Было бы неплохо уточнить для какой цели - регрессия, классификация, что-то еще...

Comment: классификация множества файлов. Спасибо, добавил в вопрос

Comment: @vadim-vaduxa этот print вместо последней строки?

Comment: @AndrewGorshenin, предоставьте больше информации - какого рода входные данные, что вы ожидаете получить на выходе? Каким классификатором хотите воспользоваться? Собственно главный вопрос - в каком виде вам нужны входные данные для классификации?

Comment: @maxu примерно 140 тысяч .htm файлов, содержащих текст на русском и английском.
На выходе ожидаются те же файлы, разделенные по папкам, соответствующие заранее известным категориям.
По классификатору не определился пока.

Comment: Поищите примеры использования `TfidfVectorizer`...

Comment: @maxu, спасибо, судя по описанию функции, это то что надо.
Я новичок в сообществе, так что могли бы вы подсказать как я могу отметить ваш ответ?

Comment: @AndrewGorshenin, тут пока нечего отмечать.. ;-). Посмотрите еше [здесь](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html) - "1.3   Document Classification"

Comment: @AndrewGorshenin, [вот эта статья](http://bbengfort.github.io/tutorials/2016/05/19/text-classification-nltk-sckit-learn.html), по-моему это отличный пример

Comment: @maxu, прошу прощения, но я не могу понять как указывается то, откуда брать тексты. В TfidfVectorizer есть параметр input, но как его использовать не могу понять. Все примеры в сети оперируют, как я понял, уже готовыми массивами данных для обработки, а примера с загрузкой текстов в память не нахожу.

Comment: @AndrewGorshenin, я добавил простенький пример в качестве ответа

Comment: Почитайте в интернете, что такое генераторы в Python и как они работают, чтобы понимать, что это за `<generator>` такой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существует много вариантов "токенизации" текстов - в итоге все будет зависеть от того какую структуру вам надо получить. Например [Bag-of-words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) - эта модель часто используется для классификации документов по частотному анализу вхождения слов.

Очень рекомендую ознакомиться с [этой статьей](http://bbengfort.github.io/tutorials/2016/05/19/text-classification-nltk-sckit-learn.html).

Вот примитивный пример токенизации HTML в `bag-of-words`:

```
import string
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

trantab = str.maketrans(string.punctuation, ' ' * len(string.punctuation))
stopwords_all = set(stopwords.words('english') + stopwords.words('russian'))

url = 'http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/614454/'
r = requests.get(url)
if r.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
    # Treat the error...
    pass

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

# stripping javascript (c) http://stackoverflow.com/a/22800287/5741205
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()    # rip it out

text = soup.get_text()
tokens = [word for word in nltk.word_tokenize(text.lower().translate(trantab))
          if word not in stopwords_all]
freq_words = nltk.FreqDist(tokens)

print(freq_words.most_common(30))
```

Вывод:

```
[('stack', 16),
 ('overflow', 11),
 ('назад', 9),
 ('import', 9),
 ('файла', 8),
 ('часов', 8),
 ('19', 7),
 ('вопрос', 6),
 ('text', 6),
 ('русском', 6),
 ('ответ', 6),
 ('folder', 5),
 ('load', 5),
 ('files', 5),
 ('words', 5),
 ('текста', 5),
 ('–', 5),
 ('python', 5),
 ('exchange', 4),
 ('0', 4),
 ('science', 4),
 ('print', 4),
 ('17', 4),
 ('maxu', 4),
 ('3', 4),
 ('регистрация', 4),
 ('голос', 4),
 ('gorshenin', 3),
 ('filename', 3),
 ('данные', 3)]
```

---

[Список популярных методов классификации (категоризации) документов](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_classification#Automatic_document_classification_.28ADC.29)

Comment: спасибо большое, разобрался

Comment: @AndrewGorshenin, рад помочь! Особенно когда тема интересная и позволяет мне научиться чему-то новому...

Comment: прошу прощения, что в той же теме, но могли бы вы подсказать русскоязычную документацию по этой библиотеке? Или другие материалы на русском?

Comment: @AndrewGorshenin, пардон, я не в курсе... я предпочитаю документацию на английском читать - не люблю "креативные" переводы

Comment: @jfs, да, действительно. `Counter` и `TfidfVectorizer` не использовались - убрал из ответа...