# Как после каждого слова вставить какой-нибудь символ?

Tags: python

Есть код:

```
i = 'пайтон скрипты монитор'   
i2 = '|'.join(i)
```

как вы уже поняли, этот код добавляет после каждой буквы символ "|", а как сделать так, чтобы этот символ добавлялся после каждого слова?

Comment: А вы не пробовали просто заменять каждый символ пробела?

Comment: блин точно, спасибо)

Comment: а лучше воспользоваться заменой по регулярному выражению - `(.*?)\s` заменять на `$1` т.е. будут убираться все whitespace символы

Comment: @VladimirNovopashin не по дзену

Comment: @Alban ваши предложения?

Comment: @VladimirNovopashin с реплейсом идеально, с регуляркой - нет

Comment: Если занудствовать, то в общем случае слова могут быть разделены не только пробелами, так что возможно с реплейсом тоже не идеально) Но это от задачи зависит, автору может и норм

Comment: @andreymal и пробелы могут быть разные. К примеру, `'\n'` или `'\xa0'`. Подробнее [Как удалить все пробелы из строки в Python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/359110/23044)

Answer (score 1):

```
i2 = '|'.join(i.split())
```

split разбивает на куски разделённые пробельными символами.

Comment: Чем минус вызван? Код работает для примера в вопросе. Формально можно в конец добавить, если заголовок буквально читать, но не похоже что автор этого хочет. В общем случае есть много способов на слова разбить ([nltk word_tokenize()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/614460/23044)), но опять таки разбиение по пробелу вполне достаточно в этом случае.